# getJsonObject trazer campo específico

Tags: java, json

Tenho um objeto que vem ao selecionar um determinado botão.

O objeto está vindo correto.

```
System.out.println(filter.getJsonObject("cadastro"));
```

Resultado:

```js
{"id":1,"createdAt":"2017-12-22T14:00:55.86","nome":"teste"}
```

Porém, preciso que me retorne somente o nome, não o objeto inteiro, como posso fazer?

Tentei `System.out.println(filter.getJsonObject("cadastro").getString("nome"));` mas não deu certo.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Você está utilizando `javax.json`?

Comment: O que aconteceu quando você tentou o `getString("nome")`? Erro de compilação? Exceção? `null`? Veio uma string diferente?

Answer (score 0):

Duas formas de recurar o nome seria:

1 -

```
 filter.getJsonObject("cadastro").optString("nome", "");
```

2 -

```
JSONObject json = filter.getJsonObject("cadastro");
String nome = json.getString("nome");
```

Na primeira opção ele vai retornar uma string vazia caso ele não consiga retornar o valor e na segunda opção, se não retornar valor ele vai te dar um     JSONException